# Is it healthy to eat the stomachs and waste organs of molluscs?

Tags: nutrition, food-safety

In the interest of brevity, I'll denote 'molluscs' to mean the phylum that includes [the different classes for clams, mussels, scallops, etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_edible_molluscs).

Ought humans to avoid consuming the stomachs and other waste organs of such animals? Or do health benefits truly exist?

For example, mussels' stomachs are disgustingly black (or blackened green). The dross filtered from the water by molluscs, does it affect the nutrition value of bivalves?

Comment: Reminding myself to answer this. It's a good question.